# Whatever the username, Hyperledger Fabric Sample App, Balance Transfer, log in successfully

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am playing around with hyperledger fabric sample apps. In "Balance transfer" app, they have provided sample requests to login user, create channel and more.....
 But whatever the username i provide, it logged it in successfully.
Request:

```
curl -s -X POST \
  http://localhost:4000/users \
  -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -d 'username=Jim&orgName=org1'
```

Response

```
{
    "success": true,
    "secret": "GSHPwdfBQyzB",
    "message": "Jim enrolled Successfully",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MTI0MjkxNzYsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiSmltIiwib3JnTmFtZSI6Im9yZzIiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTIzOTMxNzZ9.AAH5A9V08QfMvPmsDpoHVkYsFNbQX-nRMU025NziZRc"
}
```

No matter what username i provide it log it in successfully.
Can anyone explain, what is actually going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

`curl -s -X POST \
  http://localhost:4000/users \
  -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -d 'username=Jim&orgName=org1'`

registers and enrolls a user. You are sending the POST request as an admin with registration privileges.

Comment: Thank you! so how can we login a user, and how the login status of a user can be maintained between different requests to NodeJS.

Comment: To login a user, you just send a login request with the username and the secret that are returned by the registration/enrollement procedure.The login status is maintained by the means of a token generated during the login process. You might want to write some of these functions yourself.